# C# winforms message box

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I have two textboxes (username and password) that the user can update and click save and the text will write to the xml. The user can also remove those textboxes or add new ones.

I need a message box to show only if the user is deleting textboxes which textboxes have been previously saved.

At the moment the message box shows no matter what. if the text has been entered ->  save button clicked -> remove button clicked then warning appears
Otherwise if the text is entered, not saved and then removed there will be no message box.

Here is my code:

Remove button:

```
private void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want delete this user?  \n Deleting users may break workflows", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {

        int idx = RemoveButtons.IndexOf((Button)sender);

        // Remove button
        RemoveButtons[idx].Dispose();
        RemoveButtons.RemoveAt(idx);

        // Remove textbox
        UsernameTextBoxes[idx + 1].Dispose();
        UsernameTextBoxes.RemoveAt(idx + 1);

        PasswordTextboxes[idx + 1].Dispose();
        PasswordTextboxes.RemoveAt(idx + 1);

        //Shift controls up - changes the location of the textboxes 
        for (int i = idx; i < RemoveButtons.Count; i++)
        {
            RemoveButtons[i].Top -= SpaceDelta;
            UsernameTextBoxes[i + 1].Top -= SpaceDelta;
            PasswordTextboxes[i + 1].Top -= SpaceDelta;
        }

        space -= SpaceDelta;
    }
}
```

Save button:

```
private void ConfigSaveButton_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (UsernameTextBoxes.TrueForAll(t => t.Text.Length > 0) &&
      PasswordTextboxes.TrueForAll(t => t.Text.Length > 0))
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Changes saved! ", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            EnvironmentConfigManager configmgr = new EnvironmentConfigManager();

            List<EnvironmentUsersUser> UserList = _config.Environment.Users.User.Where(user => user.toDisplay == true/*.ToString()*/).ToList();
            foreach (var user in UserList)
            {
                _config.Environment.Users.User.Remove(user);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < UsernameTextBoxes.Count; i++)
            {
                var userName = UsernameTextBoxes[i];
                var password = PasswordTextboxes[i];
                var encryptPassword = PasswordEncrption.RSAEncryption(password.Text);
                _config.Environment.Users.User.Add(new EnvironmentUsersUser() {  userName = userName.Text, password = encryptPassword, toDisplay = true });
            }

            configmgr.Serilize<Config>(_configurationTabData._objectSources.getEnviromentFileName, _config);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all textboxes", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

EDIT - adding controls

global variables:

```
List<Button> RemoveButtons = new List<Button>();
List<TextBox> UsernameTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
List<TextBox> PasswordTextboxes = new List<TextBox>();
```

add the controls:

```
private void ADDUserInfo(int rowCount, string password = "", string username = "")
{
    var Password = new TextBox();
    Password.Text = password;
    Password.Location = new Point(PasswordX, PasswordY + space);
    Password.Name = "Password" + rowCount;
    Password.PasswordChar = '*';

    var Username = new TextBox();
    Username.Text = username;
    Username.Location = new Point(UsernameX, UsernameY + space);
    Username.Name = "Username" + rowCount;

    Panel.Controls.Add(Username);
    Panel.Controls.Add(Password);
    // 

    UsernameTextBoxes.Add(Username);
    PasswordTextboxes.Add(Password);

    ++NumberOfClick;
    switch (NumberOfClick)
    {
        case 1:
            var AddUserbtn = new Button();
            AddUserbtn.Name = "CAEAddUserbtn";
            AddUserbtn.Click += new EventHandler(CAEAddUserbtn_Click);
            UsersPanel.Controls.Add(CAEAddUserbtn);
            break;


        default:
            var Remove = new Button();
            Remove.Location = new Point(RemoveX, RemoveY + space);
            Remove.Click += new EventHandler(Remove_Click);
            Remove.Name = "Remove" + rowCount;
            CaeUsersPanel.Controls.Add(Remove);
            RemoveButtons.Add(Remove);
            break;
    }

    space += SpaceDelta;
}
```

Comment: We can have a simple if(UsernameTextBoxes[idx + 1].Text != "") at the start

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Button.Tag` for this:

**Save Button**:

```
private void ConfigSaveButton_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (UsernameTextBoxes.TrueForAll(t => t.Text.Length > 0) &&
        PasswordTextboxes.TrueForAll(t => t.Text.Length > 0))
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Changes saved! ", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            EnvironmentConfigManager configmgr = new EnvironmentConfigManager();

            List<EnvironmentUsersUser> UserList = _config.Environment.Users.User.Where(user => user.toDisplay == true/*.ToString()*/).ToList();

            foreach (var user in UserList)
            {
                _config.Environment.Users.User.Remove(user);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < UsernameTextBoxes.Count; i++)
            {
                var userName = UsernameTextBoxes[i];
                var password = PasswordTextboxes[i];
                RemoveButtons[i].Tag = true;
                var encryptPassword = PasswordEncrption.RSAEncryption(password.Text);
                _config.Environment.Users.User.Add(new EnvironmentUsersUser() {  userName = userName.Text, password = encryptPassword, toDisplay = true });
            }

            configmgr.Serilize<Config>(_configurationTabData._objectSources.getEnviromentFileName, _config);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all textboxes", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

**Remove Button**:

```
private void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    bool? tag = btn.Tag as bool?;        

    if(tag != null && tag == true)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want delete this user?  \n Deleting users may break workflows", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
             Delete(btn)            
        }
    }
    else
    {
         Delete(btn);
    }
 }

 private void Delete(Button btn)
 {
     int idx = RemoveButtons.IndexOf(btn);

     // Remove button
     RemoveButtons[idx].Dispose();
     RemoveButtons.RemoveAt(idx);

     // Remove textbox
     UsernameTextBoxes[idx + 1].Dispose();
     UsernameTextBoxes.RemoveAt(idx + 1);

     PasswordTextboxes[idx + 1].Dispose();
     PasswordTextboxes.RemoveAt(idx + 1);

     //Shift controls up - changes the location of the textboxes 
     for (int i = idx; i < RemoveButtons.Count; i++)
     {
         RemoveButtons[i].Top -= SpaceDelta;
         UsernameTextBoxes[i + 1].Top -= SpaceDelta;
         PasswordTextboxes[i + 1].Top -= SpaceDelta;
     }

     space -= SpaceDelta;
 }
```

Comment: i have two errors :
1) if (btn.Tag != null && (btn.Tag as bool) == true)
            {
     Error is : bool is a non nullable value type

2) int idx = RemoveButtons.IndexOf((Button)sender);

sender does not exist in this current context

Comment: Are those errors VS shows you? The second error is not from my code, since I replace it with `int idx = RemoveButtons.IndexOf(btn);`

Comment: Im getting an error that tag doesnt exist in the current context

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I've edited the code (the click event, to be specific) to be compatible with older version of Visual Studio.

Comment: visual studio 2015

Comment: still getting one error here bool? tag = btn.Tag as bool; that bool is a non nullable value type

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one question mark there. It should be  `bool? tag = btn.Tag as bool?;`. Code is edited

Comment: I have a runtime error under the save_click at RemoveButtons[i].Tag = true; that says argument out of range exception was unhandled

Comment: That means, you don't have as many removeButtons as usernameTextboxes

Comment: perhaps you should provide the code, where you build up the ui

Comment: yes this is true - i have one less remove button than username and password -- ill add that code right now